# offset/limit programmatically with python mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to process data from a database table. Loading them all simultaneously will hog most of computer resource. Heres my current code

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from sometable")
rs = cursor.fetchall()
.
# process 1: set operation
.
for a in rs:
    # process 2: put data in another db
```

Is there a way to reduce resource usage? Like getting rows bit by bit under a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cursor.fetchone()`. Read about it [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html). Example usage:

```
cursor.execute(query)
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

You can also consider using LIMIT in the mysql query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from sometable LIMIT 0, 100")
```

Finally, avoid using the star operator and only select the columns you need.

Comment: I read about it before but never knew much of the detail. Here a link containing an explanation and an example how to use fetchone : http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/25476-nonetype-object-returned-fetchone-mysqldb

Answer (score 1):

Using cursor.fetchone() will probably still cause resource issues because of the SELECT * statement before it.  I believe the best way to do this is to limit the query results with LIMIT and just loop through them all.